# What seems to be the error here in the below code?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

> Error Code: 2014 Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now

Platform- My SQL Workbench

```
DELIMITER//
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS must_watch_movies;
CREATE PROCEDURE
must_watch_movies ()
BEGIN DECLARE mTitle
VARCHAR (45);
     DECLARE mDistributor VARCHAR (45);
     DECLARE mRelease datetime;
     DECLARE result VARCHAR (1000);
     DECLARE no_records INTEGER DEFAULT FALSE;
     DECLARE cursor_movies CURSOR FOR
       SELECT title, Distributor, year (release_date)
     FROM movies WHERE gross > 200000000 ORDER BY title;

     DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET SET no_records = TRUE;

     OPEN cursor_movies;
     WHILE no_records = FALSE DO
       FETCH cursor_movies INTO mTitle, mDistributor, mRelease;
     SET result =
       CONCAT ("'", mTitle, "','" mDistributor, "','" mRelease, "|");
     END WHILE;
     CLOSE cursor_movies;
     SELECT result AS "Output";
END//
  DELIMITER;
```

CALL must_watch_movies();

The declared values match the datatypes for actual column values in the table.
like mTitle and title are the same type

Answer (score 0):

You have some errors in your code

A double SET when you decalre a handler

You have to concat result if you want all movies.

The out put must be some what more complicated, but i leave that to you

> ```
> CREATE TABLE movies (title varchar(10),Distributor varchar(19), release_date date,gross BIGINT)
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO movies VALUES('text1','text2', NOW(),200000001),('text3','text4', NOW(),200000001),('text5','text6', NOW(),200000001)
> ```

> ```
> CREATE PROCEDURE
> must_watch_movies ()
> BEGIN DECLARE mTitle
> VARCHAR (45);
>      DECLARE mDistributor VARCHAR (45);
>      DECLARE mRelease INT;
>      DECLARE result VARCHAR (1000) DEFAULT "";
>      DECLARE no_records INTEGER DEFAULT FALSE;
>      DECLARE cursor_movies CURSOR FOR
>        SELECT title, Distributor, year (release_date)
>      FROM movies WHERE gross > 200000000 ORDER BY title;
>
>      DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET  no_records = TRUE;
>
>      OPEN cursor_movies;
>      WHILE no_records = FALSE DO
>        FETCH cursor_movies INTO mTitle, mDistributor, mRelease;
>      SET result = CONCAT (result,"'", mTitle, "','", mDistributor, "','", mRelease, "|");
>      END WHILE;
>      CLOSE cursor_movies;
>      SELECT result AS "Output";
> END
> ```

> ```
> CALL must_watch_movies()
> ```
>
> ```
> | Output                                                                                   |
> | :--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | 'text1','text2','2021|'text3','text4','2021|'text5','text6','2021|'text5','text6','2021| |
>
> ✓
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9a25b69c176cc8d2b6858bed1f9d1b1e)*

Comment: Thank you! I got it to run but I get nothing as output or should I say i get null

Comment: as you see the procedure works, please change the dbfiddle and post a lonk , so that i can check it and please copy all see especial the default value for result

Comment: ThankYou. It turns out the millions were 1 for 1 million, 2 for 2 million and so on. worked finally